# Enabling PHP on the Mac

Tags: macos, mac, php

I have done all the steps for enabling php on the Mac:

- edited httpd.conf to uncomment loadmodule for php
- verified that php.conf has the right information
- have web sharing enabled

But the apache server still doesn't open my php file as a web page.  What else must I do to open php pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, restarting Apache and making sure the file you want to view ends with `.php` is all you need to do.

Comment: I think `restarting Apache` is the key here. +1 for you.